# Schedule Workflow to run daily

Tags: 2010, list, workflow, custom-list

The workflow I have sends an email to a user depending on the number of days left until a document expires (90, 60, 30, <10) in a custom list.

Is there a way to schedule a workflow to run at a designated time every day in SharePoint 2010 without having to do i manually? Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE**

Here is my proposed workflow. What do you think
[image]

Comment: This sounds like it would work better as a timer job. They are easier to schedule. A workflow needs a trigger

Comment: @Colbs is there a way ti implement a timer job without accessing SharePoint Central Administration?

Comment: you don't have access to CA? You can deploy and activate through Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

You can have a powershell script that runs on a task scheduler for the server that runs on the server everyday. You will need to load the powershell snapin at the beginning of the script and then kick off the workflow in the script. This is an example of starting a workflow on every item in the list.

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
$list = $web.Lists["Shared Documents"]

$assoc = $list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName("Workflow Name","en-US")

$data = $assoc.AssociationData
$items = $list.Items
foreach($item in $items)
 {
 $wf = $manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$assoc,$data,$true)
 }
```

Reference: http://www.thesysadminhimself.com/2013/09/sharepoint-start-workflow-all-items-powershell.html

How to create a task scheduler to run powershell: http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/17736-run-powershell-scripts-from-task-scheduler

Comment: Does this work on SharePoint 365?

Comment: no, you must use SharePoint Online PowerShell -- this is for onprem.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a powershell script like this one http://www.thesysadminhimself.com/2013/09/sharepoint-start-workflow-all-items-powershell.html and schedule the script to run using Task Scheduler on the server. Scheduling workflows is not an option out of the box. Alternatively, you can use third party software such as Nintex Workflow. A free solution could be HarePoint Workflow Scheduler.