# Send daily email with multiple News Items

Tags: 2013, workflow

I have the below business case/scenario for implementation on SharePoint.

Daily News items are issued by the Department. Currently, the Department attaches the news items to the email at the end of business day and send it. This is causing issues and flooding mailboxes.

I would like to implement the below:

1. A Document Library with a number of columns: News Title, News Date, Attachment (PDF Format)
2. The Department uploads each News items on the Document Library.
3. A workflow runs every day (at a specific time) and sends an automatic email to all users with the Title of each News Item. The Title should be linked to the PDF of the actual news item. The email should encompass only the News Items that were uploaded on that day. E.g. the email should not include news items from other days.

This way, the Department users only need to upload the news item on the document library. SharePoint and the workflow will do the rest of the work.

Is this possible? And if so, can you advice on the method to be used?

Comment: Please add the SharePoint version as a tag of your question to provide more information.

Comment: You should be able to send a daily summary using a list alert.

Answer (score 0):

1. Consider SharePoint's [**alerts**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-alert-or-subscribe-to-an-RSS-Feed-fb35047d-8dbd-412a-a5f3-f1712af14dcb#bmalert_createll), as @Christoffer proposed in comments
2. Native way of delivering news is [**RSS**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-RSS-feeds-for-a-site-or-site-collection-51d1b886-6425-40d0-8fe4-160b2b2d0c47) - and desktop Outlook supports it, as well as dozen of programs do. RSS is also useful to integrate news into other websites (SP and non-SP)
3. If you prefer a workflow for this, use **site workflow**. You'll need to figure out how to launch it once a day - check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120154/schedule-workflow-to-run-daily).

Also, I'd use usual custom list for this, not a document library.